# Input Text Forms Not Clickable - Nested DIVs

Tags: html, css

I was finishing up a website that Im doing for a friend and I ran into a problem on this page 
http://directv.spacecommand.tv/order/

(For informative purposes. He's an authorized dealer for all the companies listed on the website so were able to use content from their respective websites. We asked.)

The form that is there isnt clickable. I tried looking for a mistake but I cant seem to find out what it is. Im 17, this is my first website, im lacking some experience. So it could be something obvious. If you notice something wrong, please let me know. Thanks.

EDIT: Im using nested DIVs. Ive tried stacking them with z-index but it doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `z-index: -1` declaration in `#maincontainer`. This is causing the div to be placed beneath the `body`, making it unclickable.